# Search writable files in VSS

Tags: visual-studio, visual-sourcesafe

I have made changes in few files without checking them out. I want to know which are those files. How can I search them without taking talest version of other files?

Comment: FYI Microsoft itself is using Git, even replacing its own TFS Version Control. VSS was abandoned a very long time ago. The ability to version local changes is just one of the reasons

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos sadly programmers had no right to abandon it :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to execute show differences to find files you changed
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wa1e3c8a(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: Also, start with your focus/selection on the Project side (vs. the File side) of the VSS Browser.  You will be given the Project Difference dialog (vs. individual File Difference dialog).  Check the options you want, especially the "Recursive" checkbox (in case you have a hierarchy of sub-projects).  You get a pretty good visual report of the files that are same/different/only exist.  When there are File differences, you can then utilize VSS's File Differences dialog.

Comment: bulky but handy. Thanks :)